# What Else Do News Anchors Do?

Tags: production, news

We all know news network anchors' primary job is to sit in front of the camera and conduct the news program. But surely that's not *ALL* they do. What else do anchors at news networks typically do on an average work day when not in front of the camera? Are they merely considered "senior" journalists, so aside from being in front of the camera, they still write?

Comment: Many of them had to work hard to get there, by being a journalist first :-)

Comment: So it's more being at the "top" of the journalism "totem pole" aside from entering the executive realm?

Comment: I think they might have some insight on the news broadcast itself, some might be even the producers,

Comment: Depeneds on the station. But usually attend briefing meetings, news selection, segment sequence and so on. Let's say that to anchor 30 minutes of news you need 4 hours of production.

Comment: A friend of mine was a news anchor. I never asked her precisely what she filled her days with, but she would start at 10am in preparation for the 6pm main news.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes to this. It’s a shame if you do the “sunrise” block, although it starts at 6am, you’ll be required to get to work at 2:30am.

Comment: Suggest you watch “The Newsroom” for some insight. Plus it was awesome and cancelled before its time.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to say it, but a quick Google would have answered this.

From the [*Wiki*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/News_presenter)

> The role of the news presenter developed over time. Classically, the
> presenter would read the news from news "copy" which he may or may not
> have helped write with a or news writer. This was often taken almost
> directly from wire services and then rewritten. Prior to the
> television era, radio-news broadcasts often mixed news with opinion
> and each presenter strove for a distinctive style. These presenters
> were referred to as commentators. The last major figure to present
> commentary in a news broadcast format in the United States was Paul
> Harvey.[1]
>
> With the development of the 24-hour news cycle and dedicated cable
> news channels, the role of the anchor evolved. Anchors would still
> present material prepared for a news program, but they also
> interviewed experts about various aspects of breaking news stories,
> and themselves provided improvised commentary, all under the
> supervision of the producer, who coordinated the broadcast by
> communicating with the anchor through an earphone. Many anchors also
> write or edit news for their programs, although modern news formats
> often distinguish between anchor and commentator in an attempt to
> establish the "character" of a news anchor. The mix of "straight" news
> and commentary varies depending on the type of program and the skills
> and knowledge of the particular anchor.[2]

In short, they originally helped write the copy that was read on-air, but now (for the 24-hour news stations) they interview experts and add their own experienced commentary.